# array of objects and - (NSString *)description

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object

How can I implement `- (NSString *)description`
?

I do:

```
- (NSString *)description{
    NSString *descriptionString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self tableau]];
    return descriptionString;
}
```

and add in my ViewController

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau] description]);
```

I just obtain:

```
2013-12-03 10:47:50.323 ApplicationTest2[561:60b] (
    "<DataOrder: 0x156eb090>",
    "<DataOrder: 0x16926340>"
)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: i guess tableau is an array. And you haven't broken its object upto basic values like int, float, string etc.

Comment: no I didn't, this array contain objects of strings and floats

Comment: What do you want to get by calling `description`?

Comment: instead of this numbers i want to get the strings and floats which are in the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the description method in your model, as in the below example.

**Employee Class:**

```
@interface Employee : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *name;
@property (assign) float salary;
-(NSString *)description;
@end
```

**Implementation of Employee:**

```
@implementation Employee

-(NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@,  Salary: %f", self.name, self.salary];
}

@end
```

***If you want to add few more properties then you can concatenate with the string...***

**Now you can use it as:**

```
Employee *e1 = [Employee new];
e1.name = @"one";
e1.salary = 20000.;
Employee *e2 = [Employee new];
e2.name = @"two";
e2.salary = 45000;
Employee *e3 = [Employee new];
e3.name = @"three";
e3.salary = 12000;

NSArray *array = @[e1, e2, e3];

NSLog(@"%@",[array description]);
```

**Output:**

```
(
    "Name: one,  Salary: 20000.000000",
    "Name: two,  Salary: 45000.000000",
    "Name: three,  Salary: 12000.000000"
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement the description on your custom DataOrder object.

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@"];
}
```

After that just loop through your collection and log the objects or just log the array.

```
NSLog(@"DataOrder:%@", dataOrder);
```

Comment: tank you I will try that, and add the description in my array

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
- (NSString *)description{
    NSMutableString *returningString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (DataOrder *elmnt in tableau)
    {
        [returningString appendString:/*a string describing your element*/];
    }
    return returningString
}
```